# 2 if Issets - Not working properly

Tags: php

I have a form with inputs that have equal names, values are urls.

In the first `if ISSET` if the names exist, the variable `$urls` receives the array of names.

```
If (isset ($_POST['my_image'])) {
     $urls = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_POST['my_image']));
}
```

I transform this array from the first isset into `JSON` and I want to save it into another input.

The input I want to save looks like this:

```
<Input type="text" name="imagens_inicio" value="<?php echo $urls; ?>" />
```

And Isset of this input like this:

```
If (isset($_POST['imagens_inicio'])) {

     Update_option('imagens_inicio', $ _POST['imagens_inicio']);
}
```

It's all "working", but: when I click save the screen updates and the JSON content that is in the `$urls` variable appears in the input after refreshing the screen, without saving. To save I have to click submit again.

How do I click once on submit and already fill in the input as tbm already save in the DB, without having to double-click the submit?

Comment: just save it in the first conditional, rather than dump it into another field? `if(isset($_POST['my_image'])) {
     Update_option('imagens_inicio',htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_POST['my_image'])));
}`

Comment: you have to do save/update in single isset itself

Comment: @Steve Thanks your answer worked for me. If you want to create a response and I will mark your answer as resolved

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as expected. You are using the first submit to move the data from `$_POST['my_image']` into the form so when you submit it again you have the data in `$_POST['imagens_inicio']`.

Instead, I would suggest you change your code to something like:

```
If (isset ($_POST['my_image'])) {

     Update_option('imagens_inicio', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_POST['my_image'])));
}
```

Then you will only need to submit the form once.